# How to handle google recaptcha with jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, recaptcha

i need a little info on google recaptcha. I want to grab the value of "g-recaptcha-response" that compares in the captcha.php file i inserted below in my jquery file and then send it to the captcha.php file using jquery $.post() method. I apologize if this is duplicate but i really cannot find someone with my same problem ;)

THE HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="AlterVista - Editor HTML"/>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="handle_spam.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lf8LxIUAAAAALg93pw24l53KTeqrIwl7kUY-opk"></div>
    <button id="go">Register</button>

</body>
</html>
```

THE PHP

```
<?php
    $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    echo $captcha;       
    if(!$captcha){
        echo 'You must verify yourself';
        exit;
    }
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6Lf8LxIUAAAAACB9iqeOermR-rPOW0zcWRfoetBO&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if($response.success==false)
    {
        echo 'abort_all';
    }else
    {
        echo 'success';
    }
?>
```

THE JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#go').click(function(){
        send=$('')
        $.post('captcha.php',function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You send a post to `captcha.php` without any value, so `$captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];` will be empty. You have to get the captcha response first: [Verifying the user's response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

Comment: @empiric- Yes i know, in fact i wanted to know how to get that value to send. I'll read the page you posted thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="captchaCallback" data-sitekey="...">
```

and provide the function:

```
function captchaCallback(response) {
    alert(response);
}
```

Comment: Your solution works but i need a close "conversion" of this for jquery, storing the response in a variable, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? There is no jQuery equivalent to this. And I was alerting the response so you'd get instant feedback, but if you want to store the response, what's keeping you from doing that?

Comment: I need to send the response to my PHP page with the $.post method and I always did with jquery. I'm not an expert so how to do it with simple JavaScript? And another problem: I want to start that function when I click a button with given Id in my HTML page

Comment: No, you misunderstand: just put your `$.post()` *inside* the `captchaCallback` function

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't knew I could use it in simple JavaScript, thanks 

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript.

Comment: Yes but I thought $.post was a jquery feature only, my fault 

Comment: $.post *is* a jQuery feature. But jQuery is written in JavaScript, so you can arbitrarily combine the two. jQuery is basically this: `function $(a, b, c) { ... }`